# Javascript statement evaluation error

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP on that I have written a javascript, condition is there are four records with same product id but each having a different record id. When i am trying to update the 4th record quantity on the onchange() event but still its taking first record id. Below i am mentioning the statement in which its taking the record id

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
                //                alert(1);
                $("#SaveBtn").click(function () {
                    //                    alert(2);
                    $("#ConfirmLinePageFRM").submit();
                    //                    alert(3);
                });

                $("#UPC_EAN").change(function () {
                    //                    alert(4);
                    //                    $("#Status").html("UPC/EAN Code in Processing Plz wait");
                    val = $(this).val();
                    var flag = 0;

                    if ($("UPC_EAN").val() == 'OK') {
                   //     alert(5);
                        $("#ConfirmLinePageFRM").submit();
                    }
                    //loadXMLDoc();
                    //alert ("Product Find") ;
                    $(".Abc").each(function () {
                   //     alert(6);
                      //  alert($(this).attr("axp"));
                        if (($(this).attr("axp") == val) && (flag != 1)) {
                           // alert(7);
                            var confirmQty = $("#ConfirmQry" + $(this).val()).val();
                            var targetQty = $("#TargetQty" + $(this).val()).val();
                            var id = $(this).val();
                            if (parseInt(confirmQty) >= parseInt(targetQty)) {
                          //      alert(8);
                                flag = 2;
                            } else {
                           //     alert(9);
                                $("#UPC_EAN").val("");
                                $('#UPC_EAN').focus();
                                flag = 1;
                                var id = $("#id").val();
                                var c_id = $(this).val();
                           //     alert("before loadXMLDoc");
                                loadXMLDoc(id, c_id);
                                //$("#ConfirmQry" + $(this).val()).val(parseInt($("#ConfirmQry" + $(this).val()).val()) + 1);
                            //    alert("after loadXMLDoc");
                                //                                alert("0 :" + scanOK);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    $("#Status").html("");
                    if (flag == 0) {
                      //  alert(12);

                        $("#display-error").html("Wrong Barcode Plz Ch Again.");
                        $("#display-error1").html("");
                        $("#UPC_EAN").val("");
                        $("#UPC_EAN").focus();
                    } else {
                       // alert(13);
                        if (flag == 2) {
                         //   alert(14);

                            $("#display-error").html("All confirm qty already done");
                            $("#display-error1").html("");
                            $("#UPC_EAN").val("");
                            $("#UPC_EAN").focus();
                        } else {
                         //   alert(15);
                            $("#display-error").html("");
                        }
                    }
                   // alert("before showhide");
                    showhide();
                  //  alert("after showhide");
                });
            });



            function loadXMLDoc(id, c_id)
            {
               // alert(18);
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else
                {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {
                  //  alert("xmlhttp.readyState :" + xmlhttp.readyState);
                    //                    alert("xmlhttp.status :" + xmlhttp.status);
                    //                    alert("xmlhttp.responseText :" + xmlhttp.responseText);
                    //                    // below is for direct testing
                    //                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 0 && xmlhttp.responseText == "") {
                    //                    // below is for netbeans ide testing
                    //                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.responseText == "") {

                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 0 && xmlhttp.responseText == "") {
                        alert("Network Connection Error");
                        $("#ConfirmLinePageFRM").submit();
                    }
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        var textRespose = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if ($.trim(textRespose) == 'U') {
                            $("#display-error1").html(val + " - Updated Sucessfully");
                            $(".bgColor").css("background-color", "#aad4ff");                               
                            $(":input").css("background-color", "#aad4ff");
                            $("#UPC_EAN").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).removeAttr("readonly");

                            $("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).val(parseInt($("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).val()));

                            $("#UpcCode" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#Location" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#tQty" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#cQty" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#TargetQty" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            showhide();
                        }
                        if (xmlhttp.responseText == "" || xmlhttp.responseText == "Database conectivity issue") {
                            //                alert("Network Connection Error");
                            //                            $("#ConfirmLinePageFRM").submit();
                        }
                    }
                    //
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "AjaxLogicForManually?id=" + id + "&c_id=" + c_id, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
            function manuallyEnterValue() {
               // alert(26);
                var qtyFlag = 0;
               // alert(261);

                $(".Abc").each(function () {
                   // alert(262);
                  //  alert(val);
                  //  alert($(this).attr("axp"));
                    var scanVal = $("#Line").val();
                    //var scanVal = document.getElementById("LineNo");
                    //  var scanVal = $("input").attr("axp").val;
                    // alert($('input').attr('axp'));
                  // alert(scanVal);


                    if (($(this).attr("axp") == val) && (qtyFlag != 1)) {
                    //    alert(263);
                        var confirmQty = $("#ConfirmQry" + $(this).val()).val();
                        var targetQty = $("#TargetQty" + $(this).val()).val();
                    alert(confirmQty);
                     alert(targetQty);
                        if (parseInt(confirmQty) > parseInt(targetQty)) {
                        //    alert(28);
                            qtyFlag = 2;
                        }else{
                       //     alert(29);
                            //var qtyVal = $("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).val;
                            qtyFlag = 1;
                            var id = $("#id").val();
                            //var c_id = $(".Abc").val();
                            var c_id = $(this).val();
                           // alert(confirmQty);
                         //   alert(id);
                       //   alert(c_id);
                          //  alert("before loadXMLDoc");
                            loadXMLDocForManuallyEnter(confirmQty, id, c_id);
                         //   alert("after loadXMLDoc");
                        }
                    }
                });
                if (qtyFlag == 0) {
                   // alert(24);

                    $("#display-error").html("Wrong Barcode Plz Ch Again.");
                    $("#display-error1").html("");
                    $("#UPC_EAN").val("");
                    $("#UPC_EAN").focus();
                } else {
                  //  alert(13);
                    if (qtyFlag == 2) {
                    //    alert(14);

                        $("#display-error").html("Product Con.Qty Exceed to the Tar.Qty");
                        $("#display-error1").html("");
                        $("#UPC_EAN").val("");
                        $("#UPC_EAN").focus();
                    } else {
                     //   alert(15);
                        $("#display-error").html("");
                    }
                }
                showhide();                   
            }

            function loadXMLDocForManuallyEnter(qtyVal, id, c_id){

               // alert(228);
               // alert(qtyVal);
               // alert(id);
               // alert(c_id);
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari               
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();                
                }else
                {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {
                  //  alert("xmlhttp.readyState :" + xmlhttp.readyState);
                    //                    alert("xmlhttp.status :" + xmlhttp.status);
                    //                    alert("xmlhttp.responseText :" + xmlhttp.responseText);
                    //                    // below is for direct testing
                    //                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 0 && xmlhttp.responseText == "") {
                    //                     testing
                    //                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.responseText == "") {

                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 0 && xmlhttp.responseText == "") {
                        alert("Network Connection Error");
                        $("#ConfirmLinePageFRM").submit();

                    }
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                     //   alert(119);
                        var textRespose = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if ($.trim(textRespose) == 'U') {
                            $("#display-error1").html(val + " - Updated Sucessfully");
                            $(".bgColor").css("background-color", "#aad4ff");
                            $(":input").css("background-color", "#aad4ff");
                            $("#UPC_EAN").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).prop('readonly', true);

                            $("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).val(parseInt($("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).val()));

                            $("#UpcCode" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#Location" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#tQty" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#cQty" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#ConfirmQry" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            $("#TargetQty" + c_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                            showhide();
                        }
                        if (xmlhttp.responseText == "" || xmlhttp.responseText == "Database conectivity issue") {
                                  alert("Network Connection Error");
                            //                            $("#ConfirmLinePageFRM").submit();
                        }
                    }
                    //
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "AjaxLogicForManuallyEnterValue?id=" + id + "&c_id=" + c_id + "&qtyVal=" + qtyVal, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }

        </script>
```

its taking the record id of first record. How can I take the id of 4th record and it is happening when product id is same for all four record.

Please help me

Comment: you're going to need to post a lot more code than one line - there's absolutely no way anyone can answer without knowing the context of that one line of code

Comment: Now I added whole JS code

Comment: From one extreme to the other - are you able to produce a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ... emphasis on MINIMAL